# Open Shiny Modal dialog box by clicking on multiple divs

Tags: shiny, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, shinyapps

I have below `Shiny-app` -

```
library(shiny)

  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      useShinyjs(),  # Set up shinyjs
      div(id = "Div1", style = "height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: red;"),
      div(id = "Div2", style = "height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: blue;")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      onclick('Div1', showModal(modalDialog(
            div(id = "Div3", style = "height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: black;", tableOutput("tab")),
          )))
    }
  )
```

In this app, if I click on the `Div1` then the `Modal dialog box` will open. However I want to extend this with the condition that, if I click ANY of `Div1` or `Div2` then that same `dialog box` will open.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a workaround, as per https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs/issues/167

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        useShinyjs(),  # Set up shinyjs
        div(id = "Div1", style = "height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: red;"),
        div(id = "Div2", style = "height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: blue;")
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {

        ids <- c("Div1", "Div2")
        for (id in ids) {
            local({
                shinyjs::onclick(id, {
                    showModal(modalDialog(
                        div(id = "Div3", style = "height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: black;", tableOutput("tab")),
                    ))
                })
            })
        }
    }
)
```